# Testing Maps/Sets with QUnit (or other Unit Testing Tool)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, qunit

How do we assert for equality of ES6 Maps and Sets?

For example:

```
// ES6 Map
var m1 = new Map();
m1.set('one', 1);
var m2 = new Map();
m2.set('two', 2);
assert.deepEqual(m1,m2);     // outputs: passed.

// ES6 Set
var s1 = new Set();
s1.add(1);
var s2 = new Set();
s2.add(2);
assert.deepEqual(s1,s2);     // outputs: passed.
```

The intention is to assert that the elements of the Sets/Maps are equal. Both the both assertions should fail.

Is there an equivalent of `deepEqual` for Sets/Maps? In other words, short of manually iterating the elements, how do we test for Set/Map equality deeply?

If there is no way in QUnit, is there a unit testing tool that works for ES6 Sets and Maps?

**Edit**

In Firefox, which supports `Array.from()`, I have been comparing sets and maps by:

```
assert.deepEqual(Array.from(m1), Array.from(m2));
```

But this does not work with other browsers, which do not support `Array.from()`. Even with an `Array.from` polyfill, Chrome / IE does not work - `Array.from(set)` always produces an empty array regardless of the set contents. This is possibly due to these browsers' lack of support for generic iterables.

Secondly, reducing it into a comparison of Arrays may not be always appropriate. We would end up with what I consider to be false positives:

```
var s = new Set();
s.add([1,2]);
var m = new Map();
m.set(1,2);
assert.deepEqual(Array.from(s), Array.from(m));  // outputs: passed.
```

---

**Update**:

A patch is currently in the works at QUnit to extend `deepEqual()` to handle ES6 Sets and Maps. When that pull request gets merged in, we should be able to use `deepEqual()` to compare Sets and Maps. (-:

Comment: Since as you already know QUint won't do that for you, your question is reduced to "Is there a unit testing tool that understands ES6 Sets & Maps" (Which should probably be the title) which is "not a good question" by SO rules. Alternatively you could look for a code based answer to your requirements, but you actively reject such an answer. So what kind of answer are you looking for here?

Comment: I don't already know that QUnit won't work. There may be some way to do it, maybe not through `deepEqual`. I'm not arrogant enough to make such a claim like "QUnit won't work", hence the question. And I'm not actively rejecting code-based answers. I just wanted to highlight what I'm doing in QUnit as an approximation, and what problems it entails. The answer I'm looking for: is there a way to compare Sets/Maps it in QUnit? If not, what can I do?

Answer (score 3):

**Exhaustive Map comparison using higher-order functions**

I'm going to approach this the same way I approached array comparison in this similar answer: [*How to compare arrays in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34256998/633183)

I'm going to go thru the code bit-by-bit, but I'll have a complete runnable example at the end

---

**Shallow comparison**

First off, we're going to start with a generic Map comparison function. This way we can do all sorts of comparisons on Map objects, not just testing for equality

This `mapCompare` function agrees with our intuition about how Maps should be compared - we compare each key from `m1` against each key from `m2`. Note, this specific comparator is doing shallow comparison. We'll handle deep comparison in just a moment

```
const mapCompare = f => (m1, m2) => {
  const aux = (it, m2) => {
    let {value, done} = it.next()
    if (done) return true
    let [k, v] = value
    return f (v, m2.get(k), $=> aux(it, m2))
  }
  return aux(m1.entries(), m2) && aux(m2.entries(), m1)
}
```

The only thing that might not be immediately clear is the `$=> aux(it, m2)` thunk. Maps have a built-in generator, `.entries()`, and we can take advantage of the lazy evaluation by returning an early `false` answer as soon as non-matching key/value pair is found. That means we have to write our comparators in a slightly special way.

```
const shortCircuitEqualComparator = (a, b, k) =>
  a === b ? true && k() : false
```

`a` and `b` are *values* of `m1.get(somekey)` and `m2.get(somekey)` respectively. **iff** the two values are strictly equal (`===`), only then do we want to continue the comparison – in this case we return `true && k()` where `k()` is the remainder of the key/value pair comparison. On the other hand, if `a` and `b` do not match, we can return an early `false` and skip comparing the rest of the values – ie, we already know that `m1` and `m2` do not match if *any* `a`/`b` pair do not match.

Finally, we can define `mapEqual` - it's simple too. It's just `mapCompare` using our special `shortCircuitEqualComparator`

```
const mapEqual = mapCompare (shortCircuitEqualComparator)
```

Let's take a quick look at how this works

```
// define two maps that are equal but have keys in different order
const a = new Map([['b', 2], ['a', 1]])
const b = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2]])

// define a third map that is not equal
const c = new Map([['a', 3], ['b', 2]])

// verify results
// a === b should be true
// b === a should be true
console.log('true', mapEqual(a, b)) // true true
console.log('true', mapEqual(b, a)) // true true

// a === c should be false
// c === a should be false too
console.log('false', mapEqual(a, c)) // false false
console.log('false', mapEqual(c, a)) // false false
```

Heck yes. Things are looking good ...

---

**Deep comparisons with Rick & Morty**

Now that we have a fricken sweet `mapCompare` generic, deep comparison is a breeze. Take notice that we're actually implementing `mapDeepCompare` using `mapCompare` itself.

We use a custom comparator that simply checks if `a` and `b` are both Map objects – if so, we recurse using `mapDeepCompare` on the nested Maps; also being mindful to call `... && k()` to ensure the remaining key/value pairs are compared. If, `a` or `b` is a non-Map object, normal comparison is doing using `f` and we pass the continuation `k` along directly

```
const mapDeepCompare = f => mapCompare ((a, b, k) => {
  console.log(a, b)
  if (a instanceof Map && b instanceof Map)
    return mapDeepCompare (f) (a,b) ? true && k() : false
  else
    return f(a,b,k)
})
```

Now with `mapDeepCompare`, we can perform *any* type of deep comparison on nested Maps. Remember, *equality* is just one of the things we can be checking.

Without further ado, `mapDeepEqual`. Of importance, we get to *reuse* our `shortCircuitEqualComparator` that we defined before. This very clearly demonstrates that our comparators can be (re)used for shallow *or* deep Map comparisons.

```
const mapDeepEqual = mapDeepCompare (shortCircuitEqualComparator)
```

Let's see it work

```
// define two nested maps that are equal but have different key order
const e = new Map([
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', new Map([['c', 2]])]
])

const f = new Map([
  ['b', new Map([['c', 2]])],
  ['a', 1]
])

// define a third nested map that is not equal
const g = new Map([
  ['b', new Map([
    ['c', 3]  
  ])],
  ['a', 1]
])

// e === f should be true
// f === e should also be true
console.log('true', mapDeepEqual(e, f)) // true
console.log('true', mapDeepEqual(f, e)) // true

// e === g should be false
// g === e should also be false
console.log('false', mapDeepEqual(e, g)) // false
console.log('false', mapDeepEqual(g, e)) // false
```

OK, and just to make sure. What happens if we call `mapEqual` on our nested Maps `e` and `f`? Since `mapEqual` does *shallow* comparison, we expect that the result should be `false`

```
console.log('false', mapEqual(e, f)) // false
console.log('false', mapEqual(f, e)) // false
```

And there you have it. Shallow and deep comparison of ES6 Map objects. A nearly identical set of functions could be written to support ES6 Set. I'll leave this as an exercise for the readers.

---

**Runnable code demo**

This is all of the code above compiled into a single runnable demo. Each `console.log` call outputs `<expected>, <actual>`. So `true, true` or `false, false` would be a passing test – whereas `true, false` would be a failed test.

```js
// mapCompare :: ((a, a, (* -> Bool)) -> Bool) -> (Map(k:a), Map(k:a)) -> Bool
const mapCompare = f => (m1, m2) => {
  const aux = (it, m2) => {
    let {value, done} = it.next()
    if (done) return true
    let [k, v] = value
    return f (v, m2.get(k), $=> aux(it, m2))
  }
  return aux(m1.entries(), m2) && aux(m2.entries(), m1)
}

// mapDeepCompare :: ((a, a, (* -> Bool)) -> Bool) -> (Map(k:a), Map(k:a)) -> Bool
const mapDeepCompare = f => mapCompare ((a, b, k) => {
  if (a instanceof Map && b instanceof Map)
    return mapDeepCompare (f) (a,b) ? true && k() : false
  else
    return f(a,b,k)
})

// shortCircuitEqualComparator :: (a, a, (* -> Bool)) -> Bool
const shortCircuitEqualComparator = (a, b, k) =>
  a === b ? true && k() : false

// mapEqual :: (Map(k:a), Map(k:a)) -> Bool
const mapEqual = mapCompare (shortCircuitEqualComparator)

// mapDeepEqual :: (Map(k:a), Map(k:a)) -> Bool
const mapDeepEqual = mapDeepCompare (shortCircuitEqualComparator)
  
// fixtures
const a = new Map([['b', 2], ['a', 1]])
const b = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2]])
const c = new Map([['a', 3], ['b', 2]])
const d = new Map([['a', 1], ['c', 2]])
const e = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', new Map([['c', 2]])]])
const f = new Map([['b', new Map([['c', 2]])], ['a', 1]])
const g = new Map([['b', new Map([['c', 3]])], ['a', 1]])

// shallow comparison of two equal maps
console.log('true', mapEqual(a, b))
console.log('true', mapEqual(b, a))
// shallow comparison of two non-equal maps (differing values)
console.log('false', mapEqual(a, c))
console.log('false', mapEqual(c, a))
// shallow comparison of two other non-equal maps (differing keys)
console.log('false', mapEqual(a, d))
console.log('false', mapEqual(d, a))
// deep comparison of two equal nested maps
console.log('true', mapDeepEqual(e, f))
console.log('true', mapDeepEqual(f, e))
// deep comparison of two non-equal nested maps
console.log('false', mapDeepEqual(e, g))
console.log('false', mapDeepEqual(g, e))
// shallow comparison of two equal nested maps
console.log('false', mapEqual(e, f))
console.log('false', mapEqual(f, e))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I am currently doing, but I just can't help but feel that this is not the best approach, since `Array.from()` will result in an array comparison instead. This means a Map with an element {1: 2} will successfully match a Set with an element [1, 2].

Comment: No it won't. `[['1', 2]] !== [1,2]`

Comment: Hi, please see the Edit part of the question. I have tested it on Firefox.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at tho. Correct, IE does not support `Array.from` but it doesn't support `Map` or `Set` either... so you have a bigger problem there. I updated my answer.

Comment: Actually, IE 11 does support Set and Map... Just not the iterable part of it. Likewise for Chrome 43. So if you want to compare sets/maps, it works if you're willing to manually iterate through the contents. So the point and the question is: is there a way to deeply check equivalence without manual iteration?

Comment: @light I think this might help you https://github.com/Benvie/continuum and this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355486/when-will-i-be-able-to-use-es6-in-a-browser

Comment: @poqdavid thanks. One of those ES6 shims may be just what I need. Right now the shim I'm using does not seem to be filling the "iterable" part of Sets/Maps, probably due to IE and Chrome reporting that they support Sets/Maps and hence bypassing the polyfill altogether

Comment: Just an update to the issue: A patch is in the works at jQuery to allow QUnit's `deepEqual()` to handle ES6 Sets and Maps. Hope the next release includes this patch!

Comment: This case fails: `assert.deepEqual(Array.from(new Set([1, 2])), Array.from(new Set([2, 1])))`

Comment: @DavidBraun thanks for catching this. This answer was really old and hungry for a much-needed update. The revised solution is checked against a set of unit tests to properly ensure the behaviour we require. If there are any other questions, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

I just created a library ([@nodeguy/assert](https://github.com/NodeGuy/assert)) to solve this:

```
const assert = require('@nodeguy/assert')

// ES6 Map
var m1 = new Map();
m1.set('one', 1);
var m2 = new Map();
m2.set('two', 2);
assert.deepEqual(m1,m2);     // outputs: failed.

// ES6 Set
var s1 = new Set();
s1.add(1);
var s2 = new Set();
s2.add(2);
assert.deepEqual(s1,s2);     // outputs: failed.
```

Comment: Are you [joking](https://github.com/NodeGuy/assert/blob/master/lib/index.js#L10)? You mean you just created a lib that clobbers [`assert.deepEqual`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_deepequal_actual_expected_message) with [`lodash.isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual)? If you're going to use Lodash, it would be much better to explicitly use it in your tests directly – ie `assert.ok(_.isEqual(m1, m2))` rather than replacing node's `assert.deepEqual` entirely.

Comment: To top it off, your tests don't even assert the behaviour your promising. Not to mention the futility of writing tests against other libraries...

Comment: No, Lodash is an implementation detail and `assert.ok(_.isEqual(m1, m2))` doesn't show the values in the error message the way `assert.deepEqual` does.  My tests handle the first case I care about, hence the `0.1.1` release.  I'm open to pull requests if you'd like to add more.